# SQL - How to recover data in my view after I adjust date/time on my computer

Tags: c#, sql, datetime

I make a view to report for some product data for this month but when I adjust the date/time forward and backward a month to test if my view's data will last to the next month or not, and it is gone.

But when I change the time to the current time, my view's data back to normal.
Can you guys please explain for me about this problem and teach me how to solve it.

```
create view BCT122016 
as 
    select 
        MASACH, 
        TENSACH, 
        SOLUONGTON 
    from 
        SACH 
    where 
        MONTH(GETDATE()) = 12 
        and YEAR(GETDATE()) = 2016 
GO

select * from BCT122016
```

Comment: are you talking here about the View itself or the View data? which disappeared exactly?

Comment: do you have a code of your view?

Comment: Based on how you wrote your view its likely not returning rows for your date range. The easiest way to test this... is copy the SELECT from the view into a new query window. This way you can test to see what rows are returned based on your date range. it doesnt matter if its a view, it works the same way as a simple SELECT

Comment: @AmrElgarhy i mean the view itself stiil in there but the view data is gone

Comment: @MikkaRin create view BCT122016 as select MASACH, TENSACH, SOLUONGTON from SACH where MONTH(GETDATE()) = 12 and YEAR(GETDATE()) = 2016
select * from BCT122016
This is my code 122016 means this month and year but when i change to January 2017 the select command show there is no data in the view

Comment: because your view is using GetDate() function. but we don't know what is normal and what is no normal.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188383.aspx

Comment: @logixologist yes i just run the select command and it shows the view with no data

Comment: @mcNets i use the GetDate() function just to check the time for the report

Comment: @Châu Minh Phúc January is a 1 month. 12 is December.Try to execute select GetDate() and check what SQL server returns to you.

Comment: @MIkkaRin It's return exactly the time right now and after i adjust. But when i make that view before i adjust the time, it's mean in December :D. And then i adjust then just run the SELECT command, the view shows nothitng in it.

Comment: @MikkaRin I just have got the way to solve it! Thank you guys for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You're using GetDate() in your view, and GetDate() returns the **current date**.

Every time you change the system time GetDate() change too, and your view reflects this change returning different data.

```
create view BCT122016 
as 
    select 
        MASACH, 
        TENSACH, 
        SOLUONGTON 
    from 
        SACH 
    where 
        MONTH(GETDATE()) = 12 
        and YEAR(GETDATE()) = 2016 
GO

select * from BCT122016
```

Due to the WHERE clause, this view will return something only during December 2016.

```
where 
    MONTH(GETDATE()) = 12 
    and YEAR(GETDATE()) = 2016
```

Is a bad design to build view for an specific month/year, use the WHERE clause in select statement.

Comment: i just edited the code, the second SELECT just to check my view.
I know that the GetDate() function will returns the current date but i don't get the part where I made the view with the current time, it has been saved in the database, then i change the time and just run the second SELECT to check again and my view's data is gone.

Comment: is this sentence `select * from BCT122016` inside your view?

Comment: no, it isn't. I just use it to check the view's data.

Comment: I just find out how to solve it :D
`IF NOT EXISTS(select * FROM sys.views where name = 'BCT122016' and MONTH(GETDATE()) = 12 and YEAR(GETDATE()) = 2016)
exec
('create view BCT122016 as select MASACH, TENSACH, SOLUONGTON from SACH')`
I put the WHERE clause in the IF EXIST and it works when i adjust time!
Thank you for your help very much! Hope you will have a nice day!